# Understanding Theorem. 10.1. III Conway's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

The following is from Conway's Functional Analysis

[image]

Question Red : If an inequality holds for all elements then it hold when taking inf on any side. But : 1- What does taking infimum means for over all *functions*? 2- After taking inf an *element* is replaced with whole *set* on which the inf is taken, how do you justifty this? 3- How norm of $f+M^{\perp}$ is defined?

Question Blue : How the underlined inequality holds?

Other question : How $\rho$ is a *homomorphism* so that its combining with bijection yields ismorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question red:

Subquestion 1: Formally speaking, let $k : S \to \mathbb{R}$ be any function. Then $\inf\limits_{s \in S} k(s)$ is "the infinum of $k(s)$ over all $s$".

This notation is actually just shorthand for $\inf \{k(s) | s \in S\}$. Note that $\{k(s) | s \in S\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. So we're just taking the infimum of a set of real numbers.

In this case, you're just taking the infimum of the sets $\{||(f + g) \mathscr{M}|| : g \in \mathscr{M}^\bot\}$ and $\{||f + g|| : g \in \mathscr{M}^\bot\}$. Both of these are just ordinary sets of real numbers, and both are bounded from below and have at least one element. So the infima make sense.

In general, if $k(s) \leq j(s)$ for all $s \in S$, then $\inf\limits_{s \in S} k(s) \leq \inf\limits_{s \in S} j(s)$. This can be easily verified by showing that any lower bound of $\{k(s) | s \in S\}$ is also a lower bound for $\{j(s) | s \in S\}$.

Subquestion 2: Recall that formally speaking, $f \in \mathscr{X}^*$. But when we're dealing with $\mathscr{X}^* / \mathscr{M}^\bot$, we must deal with equivalence classes of functions. Here, $f + \mathscr{M}^\bot$ denotes the equivalence class of $f$ in $\mathscr{X}^* / \mathscr{M}^\bot$, and $||f + \mathscr{M}^\bot||$ denotes the norm of this class within the Banach space $\mathscr{X}^* / \mathscr{M}^\bot$. I believe that $||f + \mathscr{M}^\bot||$ is defined to be $\inf\limits_{g \in \mathscr{M}^\bot} ||f + g||$, though you'd have to check your book on this (it certainly makes sense given the context).

Question Blue:

Given my presumed definition of $||f + \mathscr{M}^\bot|| = \inf\limits_{g \in \mathscr{M}^\bot} ||f + g||$, we see that $||f|| = ||f + 0|| \geq \inf\limits_{g \in \mathscr{M}^\bot} ||f + g|| = ||f + \mathscr{M}^\bot||$, since $0 \in \mathscr{M}^\bot$.

Other question:

Given that $\rho$ is a linear isometry, it is clearly a homomorphism.